# Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "string[]" в "string"

Tags: c#

Помогите плиз довести до ума. есть скрипт который ищет идентичные строки в массиве и выводит в консоль их порядковый номер.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

internal sealed class Program {
  static void Main() {
    String[] arr = {
  "667577697890775788",
  "897678576456367767",
  "907896673566756787",
  "545765786766999798",
  "967854567868979789"
};

for (Int32 i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++) { // просто печатает строки массива (для наглядности)
  Console.WriteLine("String {0} : {1}", i + 1, arr[i]);
}

arr.Select((s, i) => new {s, i})
   .Where(a => a.s == "545765786766999798")
   .ToList()
   .FindAll(a => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(a.s))
   .ForEach(a => Console.WriteLine("Matched string : {0}", a.i + 1));
  }
}
```

проблема в том что не удаётся заставить его читать из файла. как передать обработчику программы данные из текстового файла в массив для обработки . я использовал File.ReadAllText и ReadAllLines но вылазят косяки

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace проверкаюсагабезнуль
{
    internal sealed class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string[] arr = {
      System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("1.txt")
     };

            for (Int32 i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            { // просто печатает строки массива (для наглядности)
                Console.WriteLine("String {0} : {1}", i + 1, arr[i]);
            }

            arr.Select((s, i) => new { s, i })
               .Where(a => a.s == "667577697890775788")
               .ToList()
               .ForEach(a => Console.WriteLine("Matched string : {0}", a.i + 
1));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замените

```
string[] arr = {
      System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("1.txt")
     };
```

на

```
  string[] arr = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("1.txt");
```

Код у вас рабочий, проблема может быть только в файле 1.txt

Comment: Чем ваш ответ отличается от того, что был представлен 6 часов назад другим человеком?

Comment: простите это от усталости.типа смотрю в книгу вижу фигу.

Comment: и всё таки чего то не хватает у меня в консоле вывело красиво все строки а вот Matched string не выдало.  это только у меня?

Comment: мда как не кручу а Matched string не выдаёт. наверное нужно переписать вторую часть

Comment: заработало.  всем агромнейшее спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Просто уберите фигурные скобки:

```
string[] arr = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("1.txt");
```

Этот метод сам по себе возвращает массив строк, не нужно пытаться сделать массив из массива.

Comment: пробовал. вапще всё косяком.

Comment: Проблему с чтением из файла это должно решать. Какого рода косяк случается и где?

Comment: Ошибка CS0622 Назначение типов массивов разрешено только через выражения инициализации массивов. Используйте выражение с оператором new

Comment: Ошибка CS0019 Оператор "==" невозможно применить к операнду типа "char" и "string".

Comment: всё очень непросто

Comment: Все выглядит так, как будто вы не убрали фигурные скобки в объявлении массива. Они используются, когда нужно поэлементно инициализировать массив, а не когда нужно получить ссылку на существующий(в данном случае ReadAllLines возвращает готовый массив).